# How do I access UDF timing counters in Apache Pig?

Tags: performance, hadoop, apache-pig

I've enabled the "pig.udf.profile" setting, as per the [documentation](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/perf.html#profiling). Now how do I dump out the values of the profiling counters? I could use PigStatusReporter, but what group name should I pass in to .getCounter()? From the original profiling [patch](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/attachment/12538873/PIG-2855.2.patch) it looks like the group name I want is the UDF FuncSpec string. What is this, or how do I get at the set of POUserFunc objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't see the UDF counters because I was running my job locally. Actually they're readily visible when running on Hadoop in the JobTracker interface.